# MIPS jal instruction: Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x400014

Tags: assembly, mips

I know I must be making a jump too large somewhere, but I can't really figure out where the problem is. I suspect that I used too many registers in the code. But the program spec says that certain values have to be stored in $s0, $s1 and #s2. Also I have to use argument registers and result registers. The only temp registers used are t0 and t1.

Pseudo code:

```
Main:
int z = 37;
input x;
input y;
sum = procedure1(x,y);
output x, y, sum;

int procedure1 (int a, int b)
a = a-b;
output a;
total = a+3b;
return total;
```

Below is my full code:

```
.data
zVar: .word 37
outputnewline: .asciiz "\n"
getInput: .asciiz "Enter an integer"
outproc1: .asciiz "procedure 1: "
outmain: .asciiz "Main: "
space: .asciiz " "

main:    
li $v0, 4            #prompt for x
la $a0, getInput
syscall

li $v0, 5            #read in x
syscall
move $s0, $v0        #store x in $s0
move $a0, $v0        #pass x using $a0

li $v0, 4            #start a new line
la $a0, outputnewline
syscall

li $v0, 4            #prompt for y
la $a0, getInput
syscall

li $v0, 5            #read in y
syscall
move $s1, $v0        #store y in $s1
move $a1, $v0        #pass y using $a1

jal procedure1

move $s2, $v0        #store sum in $s2

li $v0, 4            #print out "Main: "
la $a0, outmain
syscall

li $v0, 1            #print out x
move $a0, $s0
syscall

li $v0, 4            #print out " "
la $a0, space
syscall

li $v0, 1            #print out y
move $a0, $s1
syscall

li $v0, 4            #print out " "
la $a0, space
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s2
syscall

li $v0, 4            #start a new line
la $a0, outputnewline
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall              #exits the program

procedure1:
sub $t0, $a0, $a1    #a=a-b, store a in $t0
addi $sp, $sp, -12
sw $a0, 0($sp)       #put a on stack
sw $a1, 4($sp)       #put b on stack
sw $s0, 8($sp)       #put $s0 on stack

li $v0, 4            #print out "procdure 1: "
la $a0, outproc1
syscall

li $v0, 1            #print out a
move $a0, $t0
syscall

li $v0, 4            #start a new line
la $a0, outputnewline
syscall

lw $a0, 0($sp)       #restore a
lw $a1, 4($sp)       #restore b

add $t1, $zero, 3   #operand 3
mult $a1, $t1        # 3*b
mflo $s0             #store 3b in $s0
add $s0, $s0, $a0    #store a+3b in $s0
move $v0, $s0        #store total in $v0

lw $s0, 8($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr $ra
```

Comment: Don't put your code in the `.data` section. Put your initialized data in `.data` and your code in `.text`

Comment: If @Michael's comment doesn't solve your issue, you can `la $reg, function; jalr $reg` to call a function anywhere in 32-bit address space.

Comment: That fixed the problem. I'll make sure to put code in.text section from now on. Thank you for the note!